# How to get parameter of an arrow function inside another function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I want to create a functions that returns the parameter of another function. I know I can use `argument` or rest operator to access parameter inside a function itself, but how can I get them outside that function?

```js
const returnValue = (fn) => {
 //How can I get the parameter of fn? Assume I know its arity.
}
```

For example:

```
const foo = 'bar'
const hello = 'world'

const returnFirstArgument = (val1, val2) => val1

const returnArgumentByPosition = (fn, num) => {
//Take fn as input, return one of its parameter by number
}

const returnSecondArgument = returnArgumentByPosition(returnFirstArgument(foo, hello), 1) //Expect it returns 'world'
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what `returnValue()` would look like when being called (ie: what input you would give it?) and what you expect to get as a result?

Comment: I have updated with an example.  Not sure if something like this is possible to implement, but I guess it could be very useful.

Comment: It's not possible to do without modifying how `returnFirstArgument` behaves. JS will first evaluate `returnFirstArgument(foo, hello)`  and then it'll invoke `returnArgumentByPosition` with the evaluated arguments. So `fn` inside  `returnArgumentByPosition` will just be a string and won't have any knowledge of "where" it came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want isn't possible to do without modifying how `returnFirstArgument` behaves. Take for example the below piece of code:

```
const x = 1 + 2;
console.log(x); // 3
```

Before a value is assigned to `x`, the expression `1 + 2` needs to be evaluated to a value. In this case `1 + 2` gets evaluated to `3`, so `x` gets assigned to `3`, that way when we print it, it prints the literal number `3` out in the console. Since it is now just a number, we can't tell how `3` was derived (it could have come from `0 + 3`, `1 * 3`, etc...).

Now take a similar example below:

```
const max = Math.max(1, 2);
console.log(max); // 2
```

The same idea here applies from above. First `Math.max(1, 2)` is evaluated to the value of `2`, which is then assigned to `max`. Again, we have no way of telling how `2` was derived.

Now consider a function:

```
const add = (x, y) => x + y;
const ans = add(1 + 2, Math.max(1, 2));
console.log(ans); // 5
```

When we call the function, the function's arguments are first evaluated to values. The parameters within the function are then assigned to copies of these values:

```
const ans = add(1 + 2, Math.max(1, 2));
//               ^--------^------------- both evaluate first before function is invoked
```

so the above function call becomes:

```
const ans = add(3, 2);
```

As a result, inside the add function, `x` becomes `3` and `y` becomes `2`. Just like with the above first two examples with variables, we have no way of knowing the `3` came from the expression `1+2` and that `2` came from the function call of `Math.max(1, 2)`.

So, relating this back to your original question. Your function call is analogous to the add function call shown above:

```
const returnSecondArgument = returnArgumentByPosition(returnFirstArgument(foo, hello), 1)
```

just like in the other examples, the arguments passed to the function can't be expressions, so they need to be evaluated first to values. `returnFirstArgument(foo, hello)` is evaluated to a value before the `returnArgumentByPosition` function is invoked. It will evaluate to the string `"bar"`. This results in `fn` becoming `"bar"` inside of your `returnArgumentByPosition`. As `"bar"` is just a string, we again have to way of telling where it came from, and so, won't have access to the function which created it. As a result, we can't access the second argument of the function, since this information is not retained anywhere.

---

One approach to do what you're after is to create a `recall` function. The recall function is able to "save" the arguments you passed into it, and then expose them later. Put simply, it wraps your original function but is able to save the arguments and the result of calling your original function:

```js
const recall = fn => (...args) => {
  return {
    args,
    result: fn(...args),
  }
};

const add = recall((x, y) => x + y);
const getN = ({args}, n) => {
  return args[n]; 
}
const res = getN(add(1, 2), 1);
console.log(res);
```

The above approach means that `add()` will return an object. To get the result of calling add, you can use `.result`. The same idea applies to get the arguments of `add()`. You can use `.args` on the returned object. This way of saving data is fine, however, if you want a more functional approach, you can save the data as arguments to a function:

```js
const recall = fn => (...args) => {
  return selector => selector(
    args, // arguments
    fn(...args) // result
  );
};

// Selectors
const args = args => args;
const result = (_, result) => result;

const getN = (wrapped, n) => {
  return wrapped(args)[n]; 
}

const add = recall((x, y) => x + y);
const wrappedAns = add(1, 2);
const nth = getN(wrappedAns, 1);

console.log(nth); // the second argument
console.log(wrappedAns(result)); // result of 1 + 2
```

above, rather than returning an object like we were before, we're instead returning a function of the form:

```
return selector => selector(args, fn(...args));
```

here you can see that `selector` is a function itself which gets passed the arguments as well as the result of calling `fn()` (ie: your addition function). Above, I have defined two selector functions, one called `args` and another called `result`. If the `selector` above is the `args` function then it will be passed `args` as the first argument, which it then returns. Similarly, if the `selector` function above is the `result` function, it will get passed both the `args` and the result of calling `fn`, and will return the result the return value of `fn(...args)`.

Tidying up the above (removing explicit returns etc) and applying it to your example we get the following:

```js
const foo = 'bar';
const hello = 'world';
const recall = fn => (...args) => sel => sel(args, fn(...args));

const returnFirstArgument = recall((val1, val2) => val1);
const returnArgumentByPosition = (fn, num) => fn(x => x)[num];

const returnSecondArgument = returnArgumentByPosition(returnFirstArgument(foo, hello), 1);
console.log(returnSecondArgument); // world
```

---

**Side note (for an approach using combinators):**

In functional programming, there is a concept of combinators. Combinators are functions which can be used as a basis to form other (more useful) functions.

One combinator is the identity-function, which simply takes its first argument and returns it:

```
const I = x => x;
```

Another combinator is the K-combinator, which has the following structure:

```
const K = x => y => x;
```

You may have noticed that the first selector function `args` is missing an argument. This is because JavaScript doesn't require you to enter all the parameters that are passed as arguments into the function definition, instead, you can list only the ones you need. If we were to rewrite the `args` function so that it showed all the arguments that it takes, then it would have the following structure:

```
const args = (args, result) => args;
```

If we curry the arguments of this function, we get:

```
const args = args => result => args;
```

If you compare this function to the K-combinator above, it has the exact same shape. The K-combinator returns the first curried argument, and ignores the rest, the same applies with our `args` function. So, we can say that `args = K`.

Similarly, we can do a similar thing for the `result` selector shown above. First, we can curry the arguments of the results selector:

```
const result = _ => result => result;
```

Notice that this *almost* has the same shape as the `K` combinator, except that we're returning the second argument rather than the first. If we pass the identify function into the K-combinator like so `K(I)`, we get the following:

```
const K = x => y => x;
K(I) returns y => I
```

As we know that `I` is `x => x`, we can rewrite the returned value of `y => I` in terms of x:

```
y => I
can be written as...
y => x => x;
```

We can then [alpha-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence) (change the name of `y` to `_` and `x` to `result`) to get `_ => result => result`. This now is the exact same result as the curried `result` function. Changing variable names like this is perfectly fine, as they still refer to the same thing once changed.

So, if we modify how `selector` is called in the recall function so that it is now curried, we can make use of the `I` and `K` combinators:

```js
const I = x => x;
const K = x => y => x;
const recall = fn => (...args) => sel => sel(args)(fn(...args));

const args = K;
const result = K(I);

const getN = (fn, n) => fn(args)[n]; 
const add = recall((x, y) => x + y);

const addFn = add(1, 2);
const nth = getN(addFn, 1);

console.log(nth); // the second argument
console.log(addFn(result)); // result of 1 + 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation and pointing out what have I missed.

Comment: If the function is curried, partially completed but not called, is it possible to get its parameter with another function?

Comment: @JohnWinston I've added further details to my answer for a few possible solutions. I don't think currying the input function will help that much here, as you can't access the closed-over input arguments from outside the function itself.

Comment: Thank you so muck Nick!  Your explanation is really clear, and the last example does remind me how FP related with Maths.  I will try to understand all these and make my own solution, and I hope I can show you soon.

Comment: @JohnWinston no worries . Yeah, it is related a lot to Maths, there are even formal logical ways to write this sort of stuff out on paper (see [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) if you're interested)

Comment: what would be your recommended approach for learning FP and lambda calculus?  How deep do I need to dig into lambda in order to be a better FP programmer? I have read this repo https://gist.github.com/Avaq/1f0636ec5c8d6aed2e45 and the resources listed in it, and I guess it will take a long time for me to master them all.

Comment: @JohnWinston I think a good way to get better at FP is to use a functional programming language such as haskell. It's not an easy language to learn, but it forces you to use FP concepts such as currying etc. I'm not an FP expert and I only know around 3/4 of the combinators listed on that github page. But I think that trying to work with a language which has a strong focus on FP will definitly force your mind to start thinking in ways that invole functional solutions, which over time, will help improve your FP ability.